# Redirect Url (Homepage) to another url

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how I can redirect my homepage url to another url as my homepage?

If I have to add my site can you please put "yoursite" instead of example.

And will it work for both `www.` and non `www.`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 / /redirect/path/
```

The first `/` is the original path and represents `yoursite.com/`. The `/redirect/path/` part you need to change to where you want your homepage to redirect to.

Comment: so i put `Redirect 301 / /redirect/mysite.com/` didnt work also put `Redirect 301 / /mysite.com/` didnt work any help thank you

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to an entirely different domain? My example was for redirecting a url on the same domain. You don't put the domain name in the redirect path.